# List finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two questions:

**1.** How to list(up to isomorphism) all finite abelian groups of order 675, which don't have elements of order 45?

**2.** How to list(up to isomorphism) all finite abelian groups of order 196, which have cyclic group of order 98?

I just don't understand how to start. Please help me understand what's going on.

Comment: Factor the order of the group. As user627482 suggests, the fundamental theorem will give you all nonisomorphic abelian groups of that order (be mindful that $ \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime). Now decide which of these possibilities satisfy the criteria you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups